# How to Disable "Chrome --disable-web-security" in Jmeter Webdriver Sampler?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to Performance Test one of our web Applications which has Security feature enabled using JMeter and we are unable to pass **Chrome --disable-web-security** in webdriver Sampler and was wondering do we have any option to pass `Chrome --disable-web-security` when the webdriver sampler launches the chrome Browser ?

Below is the sample command line which we are using to disable web security manually to test the application.

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="chrome"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot, you can ask WebDriver Sampler plugin developers or maintainers to include this option into one of the future releases via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime you can switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write your Selenium-related code in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), it will give you full control and flexibility, example code:

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', '/path/to/chromedriver')

def options = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments('--disable-web-security')

def chromedriver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(options)
chromedriver.get('http://example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri and wanted to ask whether we can use JMeter to measure  performance on TV apps in physical devices

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Chrome Driver Config Option, "Allow Insecure Certs" worked well for my requirement.Could be worth a try.

[Chrome Driver Config Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyluH.png)